# JavaScript Handler Calls - How to Implement this Structure?

Tags: methods, javascript

Not sure what to call this post exactly.  I want to mimic a structure I've seen in Facebook, but I'm not actually using Facebook, this was a good example. I remember from using the Facebook API that it had a method that did:

```
FB_RequireFeatures(<key>, <handler>)
```

This method essentially said if the feature was ready to go at the time of the function call, the handler was immediately invoked.  If not, it was queued and called when it was available.

I think I understand how to implement something like this on my own, but I wanted to see if anyone else has done this, if you could send me a link, it would be very helpful to see.

I guess I am also implementing something similar to JQuery's ready event; if the event has already past, the handler is immediately fired (I think), but if not, the handler is queued.

Thanks.